# Share Intent with Bluetooth Option Only

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, share

I am trying to send a file over bluetooth using my app.
I already changed the mime type to something random as asdxasd/asdxa
And the file has an extension that I need to use, that is .sso

When I use the share intent it only appears the bluetooth and gmail option, but can't I delete the gmail option from the list ?

Thanks alot in advance!
I am using this code to send it using the intent:

```
file = new FileSystem(this).saveTemp();

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

sharingIntent.setType("test/onlineconfig");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Config Using"));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(picURI);

sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image"));
```

Comment: @DarkLink it's pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

if you have the path of image of device then use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image"));
```

Comment: This might be an old question. I just wanted to ask if it is possible to send the file directly without showing the bluetooth paired devices option?